# MinionPro kerning math mode and punction (comma)

Tags: math-mode, kerning, minionpro

I'm trying to write a short explantion of the quantities in a formula but I think the kerning doesn't really work. (or I'm wrong?)`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[fullfamily,opticals,minionint,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}     
\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][with:]
{#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{${}-{}$} p{10cm}}}
    {\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}

\begin{conditions}
    W,~L,~t_{\mathrm{OX,eff}}                                   &  $\dots$\\
    \textit{W\textnormal{,}}~\textit{L\textnormal{,}}~t_{\mathrm{OX,eff}} &  $\dots$\\
    \mathit{W,~L,}~t_{\mathrm{OX,eff}}                  &  $\dots$
\end{conditions}

\end{document}
```

The image shows the MWE with `cm` as well as `minonpro` but it seems like the kerning ist worse in mminion.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll analyze the case of Computer Modern, because I don't have Minion, with the following input file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\showoutput

$W,$

$\textit{W,}$

$\mathit{W,}$
\end{document}
```

showing what `\showoutput` writes in the log file.

### Case 1: `$W,$`

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 W
....\kern1.3889
....\kern-1.66667
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ;
....\mathoff
```

The first kern is the italic correction, that TeX adds after an ordinary symbol, if it has one defined, the second one is the kerning between W and comma, as defined by the font.

### Case 2: `\textit{W,}`

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.83331+1.94444)x13.05548
.....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 W
.....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 ,
....\mathoff
```

The two characters are typeset in the text italic font, with no kerning because there's none defined between them.

### Case 3: `$\mathit{W,}$`

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.83331+1.94444)x14.60272
.....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 W
.....\kern1.8361
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ;
....\mathoff
```

TeX adds the italic correction for W, as in case 1, but there's no kerning because the two characters are from different font. With `$\mathit{W},$` (which is more correct), we'd get

```
....\mathon
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 W
....\kern1.8361
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ;
....\mathoff
```

No additional box is used, because `\mathit` involves only one character.

### General notes

We see a semicolon where a comma would be expected, because the math comma in a font under the OML encoding is in the place of the semicolon: the math code of the comma is `"613B`, which means punctuation (`6`), from math group `1` and slot `3B` (which in ASCII is the semicolon).

### What happens with Minion?

The Minion font has, as far as I know, some very dramatic kerning between letters and punctuation (for instance the apostrophe). This shows very well in case 2, where text mode, rather than math mode, is used. In cases 1 and 3, the kerning is absent possibly because the W is taken from a different font than the math letter one, so case 1 and 3 are essentially the same; one should examine the math font setup in `MinionPro.sty` and the font metric files to know precisely: it's very possible that the package defines math italic just as text italic.

### What should be done?

The input should be `$W$, $L$, $t_{\mathrm{OX,eff}}$`, because these are three distinct formulas and the commas are textual, not mathematical.

Comment: Thanks for your command, I will look in to it, tomorrow. But isn't the kerning for case 2 `\textit{W\textnormal{,}}~\textit{L\textnormal{,}}~t_{\mathrm{OX,eff}}` correct or should there be a bigger space as in the text body between `$W$` and the comma?

Comment: @harryhaller No, it's incorrect. See the last paragraph.